# Cannot create an object of type 'System.Nullable` from its string representation 'null' in user control proerty

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webusercontrol

I have a user control like this

```
<uc1:wucSwitchButton3States runat="server" State="true" ID="wucSwitchButton3States" />
```

in the user control code behind I have declared a nullable property named **state**

```
public bool? State { get; set; }
```

if I set **State** as **true** of **false** it works fine but if I set it as **null** like this

```
<uc1:wucSwitchButton3States runat="server" State="null" ID="wucSwitchButton3States" />
```

I encounter with following error:

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Nullable`... from its string
>   representation 'null' for the 'State' property.

I even tried `State=""` and `State="<%=null%>"` but none of them solved the issue, do you have any idea to resolve the problem?

Comment: Why use a nullable bool in the first place?

Comment: What happens if you just omit the attribute and thereby use the default value for nullable objects?

Comment: It's a 3 states switch button which is supposed to be used in three states as a `bool?` is used, so we have three states for that, **true**, **false** and **null**, just like what you use in fields of a data base table.

Comment: And so if you ommit the attribute as OnkelToob suggests, doesn't it act as `null` ?

Comment: It's a good suggestion to omit the **state** property and consider the default value as **null** but it's a work around,it solves the issue although it's not a exact solution.

Comment: did you try {x:Null} ??

Comment: I even tried `State="{x:Null}"` as @Marco suggested but I faced the same error message again.

Comment: This is strange. I know that this works fine <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Null}" IsThreeState="True"/>. Perhaps you check the source code of the CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

based on the CheckBox Code, id did not try it myself but:

```
bool _state;

[TypeConverter(typeof(NullableBoolConverter))]
public bool? State
{
   get { return _state; }
   set { _state = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```